# How to ignore cherry-picked commits when listing commits difference with a fully merged branch

Tags: git, git-log, git-cherry-pick

In a branching model where one branch A is always merged into another B, how can I list all commits in B but not in A while ignoring all cherry-picked commits and merges?

```
     a1-------b2' -- A
   /    \       \
 b1--b2--m1--b3--m2--b4 -- B

b2': cherry-picked commit
```

In this case, it should list commits `b3, b4`.

Some research in the git manual:
Ignoring merges and cherry-picked commits is already addressed by the `--no-merges` and `--cherry-*` options of the `git-log` command. But the `--cherry-*` ones use the commits symmetric difference (that is `A...B`) to match cherry-picks together. In this example, commit b2 is not part of it. `git log --cherry A...B` returns `b2, b3, b4`.

You can reproduce the example with:

```sh
mkdir reprod; cd reprod; git init
git check-out -b B
git commit -m "b1" --allow-empty
git commit -m "b2" --allow-empty
git check-out -b A B^{/b1}
git commit -m "a1" --allow-empty
git cherry-pick --allow-empty B^{/b2}
git check-out B
git merge A^{/a1} --no-edit
git commit -m "b3" --allow-empty
git merge A^{/b2} --no-edit
git commit -m "b4" --allow-empty
git log A...B --cherry
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Failed hypothesis - kept here for history only)*

It seems you'd have to use `--left-only` / `--right-only` here.

See in this [paragraph](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---right-only).

> For example, `--cherry-pick --right-only A...B` omits those commits from B which are in A or are patch-equivalent to a commit in A. In other words, this lists the + commits from `git cherry A B`. More precisely, `--cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges` gives the exact list.

Isn't it your exact case?

Comment: I added a command script to reproduce the example. You can see for yourself :).

Comment: @montrivo I think you're actually right. Interesting question indeed :-)